# Java Firebase: No Exception when failed to authenticate

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

As Firebase SDK create a demon thread in background to synchronize data. I use the solution suggested as the link to create an AtomicBoolean to wait until the task completed.

[java Firebase: delay exit until writes finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26092632/java-firebase-delay-exit-until-writes-finish)

I tried to **remove the key in the web admin console**. The task become never completed without any timeout exception.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    InputStream serviceAccount = Appl.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("testing-fcf995d2ab6f.json");

    FirebaseOptions.Builder builder = new FirebaseOptions.Builder();
    builder.setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount));
    builder.setDatabaseUrl("https://golden-attic-93815.firebaseio.com/");
    FirebaseOptions firebaseOptions = builder.build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(firebaseOptions);

    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    DatabaseReference ref = firebaseDatabase.getReference("techoffice/database/example");

    DatabaseReference usersRef = ref.child("users");

    final AtomicBoolean done = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    Map<String, User> users = new HashMap<String, User>();
    users.put("testerA", new User("Tester A"));
    users.put("testerB", new User("Tester B"));
    usersRef.setValue(users, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener(){
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError error, DatabaseReference ref) {
            if (error != null){
                System.err.println("Error " + error.getMessage());
            }else {
                System.out.println("Completed");
            }
            done.set(true);
        }
    });
    while(!done.get());
}
```

I get the same result if I change to setValueAsync.

```
ApiFuture<Void> apiFuture = usersRef.setValueAsync(users);
apiFuture.get();
```

Comment: how you can tell the **"The task become never completed"** , add this line at end of your main function `System.out.println("Task Completed");` , what do you get now

Comment: If I add "System.out.println("Task Completed");", The Task is also not stopped. Because "while(!done.get());" always return false.

Comment: i think you can use `usersRef.setValueAsync(users)` method which returns ApiFuture and if you want to wait write operation you may check `ApiFuture.isDone()`.

Comment: I get same result. For ApiFuture<Void> apiFuture = usersRef.setValueAsync(users);
apiFuture.get();

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you can change the value of your `done` AtomicBoolean variable. Using your code it will always be `false` because `onComplete()` method is called `asynchronous`, which means that by the time you are using this line of code:

```
while(!done.get());
```

You haven't get the data yet from your database. So to solve this, you need to change the logic of your code and use a `callback`. This means that you need to wait for the data and after that to be able to use that statement. This is a classic issue with asynchronous APIs and for that I recomand you read my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774). The `onDataChange()` method is called in the same way. Please see also the last part of my answer in which I have exaplained how to get the data outside.

Comment: I have changed to apiFuture.get()

Comment: And?  What happened?

Comment: The same result

Comment: Ok, but I didn't adviced you to use `apiFuture.get()` I adviced you to use my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774). Have you even tried it?

Comment: Tested with your answer. If apiFuture.get() do not use, the Listener would not be triggered because the daemon thread would be killed.

Comment: Does your client connect to Firebase? Can you execute a read?